# Docker VPN IPSec client without privileged access

Tags: docker, vpn

I have a mysql database which I can access only after establishing VPN connection (IpSec-shared-secret + username + password)

so I want to run an isolated docker container which will establish this connection and proxy/expose mysql port somehow so that other containers can just connect to it without knowing if there is an vpn connection

all the examples I can find - require privileged access to a host/network (which I want to avoid to fully isolate container logic)

all I want is expose mysql port from a container that can establish ipsec-vpn access to a remote host`s mysql port

Comment: I once had a similar situation but then had to give up because of not finding much information. If you do find some solution keep do post a solution

Comment: Whatever the case may be NET_ADMIN capabilities will still be needed by the container

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without privileged access, but `NET_ADMIN` capabilities is required, so that the container can created and tunnel interface.

To test the config I picked up a free VPN service from

https://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn

Downloading this [file] (https://www.vpnbook.com/free-openvpn-account/VPNBook.com-OpenVPN-US1.zip)

I created below `Dockerfile` for the same

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt update && apt install -y openvpn curl socat wget ca-certificates openssl
WORKDIR /openvpn/config
COPY vpnbook-us1-tcp80.ovpn .
COPY start.sh /start.sh
ENV OPENVPN_USERNAME=vpnbook OPENVPN_PASSWORD=dup2atu
CMD /start.sh
```

In the `vpnbook-us1-tcp80.ovpn`, I made a small changed to `auth-user-pass` and made it `auth-user-pass openvpn-credentials`, so we can pass credentials from a file. Next was to create a `start.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p /dev/net && mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200

printf "$OPENVPN_USERNAME\n$OPENVPN_PASSWORD" > openvpn-credentials
chmod 600 openvpn-credentials

socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:ipinfo.io:80 2>&1 >/dev/null &
exec openvpn --inactive 3600 --ping 10 --ping-exit 60 --config vpnbook-us1-tcp80.ovpn
```

The `mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200` creates a tun device at run-time inside container so we don't need to map it from host.

Since you wanted other containers to access mysql by connecting to this container, you will change below

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:ipinfo.io:80 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```

to

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:3306,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:<YourMYSQLIP>:3306 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```

What this would do is listen to local port X on container and forward that request to port Y on IP/domain your provide. Then we can either map this ports to Host or access them directly through container.

To run the whole thing I made a simple `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  vpn:
    build: .
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    ports:
      - 3306:3006
      - 8080:80
    dns:
      - 8.8.8.8
```

Now after doing `docker-compose up -d` and waiting for few seconds, I run below command on my host

```
$ curl -H "Host: ipinfo.io" localhost:8080/json
{
  "ip": "198.7.62.204",
  "hostname": "us1.vpnbook.com",
  "city": "Manassas",
  "region": "Virginia",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "38.7701,-77.6321",
  "org": "AS30633 Leaseweb USA, Inc.",
  "postal": "20109"
}
```

As you can see `localhost:8080` was mapped to container port `80` and `socat` is forwarding that port `80` to `ipinfo.io:80`. The forwarding is happening through the VPN