# Create OpenVPN connection from docker container

Tags: docker, vpn, openvpn

I have a simple docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

USER root

RUN apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install openvpn

COPY . /tmp
```

where . contains all necessary information about the vpn connection (ovpn file, ca file, user certificate and key).

Building and running the container via `docker run -it --device=/dev/net/tun`, then changing to /tmp directory and executing `sudo openvpn config.ovpn` I get the following error:

```
Fri Aug 23 06:15:21 2019 ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
```

[EDIT] Starting the .ovpn configuration via the OpenVPN GUI works fine.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `--cap-add=net_admin` in addition to `--device=/dev/net/tun`.

Comment: Yay, using this command I get a new error - the connection is nearly established. 
Can you maybe also help out with this: 

Thu Aug 22 18:16:07 2019 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.170/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255

Thu Aug 22 18:16:07 2019 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.1

RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Thu Aug 22 18:16:07 2019 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2

Comment: Please update the question and put the formatted output there - it's hard to perceive it in one line :)

Comment: Yeah, right, I updated the question. :)

Comment: This one seems to be related to the connection configuration itself rather than to Docker... Unless your Docker network uses the same network as your VPN tries.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that... Although the OpenVPN GUI client can manage the configuration perfectly fine :o do you have any other idea?

Comment: No, sorry, no immediate thoughts. It would be nice to see your client configuration (without sensitive parameters) and (if accessible) the server one for further troubleshooting. And just to check - ensure that you don't have similar route in your container before the connection attempt.

Comment: And regarding GUI client: I'm not sure that it works identically to the CLI. Recently [we've faced an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186289/cannot-ssh-from-container-with-openvpn) when `NetworkManager` was overriding the OVPN configuration and handled routes setup on its own, so the connection profile worked well with NM, but not with OVPN CLI. Maybe there is some difference between OVPN GUI and CLI in similar way (though this is less probable, of course).

Comment: It worked after your first comment - I just did not know I could not ping the target URL. Thanks a lot for your help. If you make your comment an answer, Ill mark it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `sudo` in your case does not change anything. It is not the ultimate solution for "Permission denied" kind of issues. This especially does not work when your container already runs on behalf of `root`.

Privileged actions in Linux are governed by *capabilities*, which represent permissions for specific privileged operations. To keep this model compatible with classic UNIX model the processes running on behalf of `root` by default have all capabilities. For example, things like `sudo`, which escalate your UID to `0`, **also** grant you a full set of capabilities.

However, this is not true in containers — the amount of capabilities being available to the process in the container (even `root`-owned) is limited by so-called *bounding set*, which by default contains very limited amount of capabilities, when running in Docker:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu:14.04
root@fe50edf72783:/# capsh --print

Current: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,
cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,
cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap+eip

Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,
cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,
cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap
```

Network administration (interfaces configuration, etc.) requires `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability. As you see, it is not in the default bounding set of Docker containers, so you need to add it explicitly using `--cap-add=net_admin`:

```
docker run -it --device=/dev/net/tun --cap-add=net_admin
```

After this, you will have this capability in the container. Considering that you run it on behalf of `root`, having this capability makes using `sudo` useless (it will not grant you more capabilities than now), so you may drop it and run OpenVPN simply with `openvpn config.ovpn`.